# How can I sync other branch with mine while keeping specific directories?

Tags: git

Here is what I did:

- I have a "my_branch" and there is a "master" branch.
- I kept committing my work to "my_branch" for, say one month.
- To align with code in "master", for every 2 or 3 days, I merge master into "my_branch".
- I change code under "my_dir/" only, while nobody else touched this directory
- Other people change code under "somebody1/", "somebody2/" etc., but I had never touched.

Here is my problem:

- For some reason which I don't know, files under directories other than "my_dir/" (which I didn't touch them) are not as same as what in "master".
- One possible cause might be, when merging "master" into "my_branch", some files under directories other than "my_dir/" changed, and there were conflicts. Maybe I chose "resolve conflict" rather than "use theirs", and made me touched those files unintentionally.
- Even if I keep merge "master" into "my_branch", those unintentionally changed files never get synchronized unless they are changed by somebody else in master.
- If I merge "my_branch" into "master", files under directories other than "my_dir/" and inconsist with "master" will be changed because of "my_branch", and that's not what I want.

Here is what I want to do:

How can I make files other than "my_dir/" in "my_branch" to be same with "master", while keep files under "my_dir/" to be same with "my_branch"? One possible way is that I checkout "master", copy all files under directories like "somebody1/", "somebody2/" etc., to some place else, then checkout "my_branch", then copy those files back to my working directory and then commit.

But How can I do it with Git command? Does Git provide such util?

Comment: @RomainValeri thank you for pointing it out, I've changed that description

Comment: Instead of merging `master` into `my_branch`, consider using `git rebase master` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your branch, assuming your remote is named `origin`

```
git fetch
git restore --source=origin/master .
git restore --source=my_branch my_dir/
git commit -am "Resynced everything but my_dir with master"
```

---

**Edit after comments :** in case you're running a version of git prior to 2.20.1 (thanks Vespene Gas for the reminder), you won't be able to use `git restore`. The alternative is the older command `git checkout <ref> [-- <path> [<other_path>]]`. Then again, as Matt rightfully pointed out, you might need to get rid of unwanted files in your repo after the operation with something like `git clean`)

Comment: Before checking out all files from master, you probably need to delete the files in the other directories because the checkout won't do this.

Comment: @Matt You're right, it might be needed depending on the context.

Comment: Alternatively to the first `checkout`, you might prefer using `git restore --source=master`, *this* will really sync, even if there were unwanted files. Edited, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Nice, I just tested your method with `git restore` and it works as intended. This seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: `checkout` is still in my muscle memory, but `switch` and `restore` are indeed useful additions.

Comment: I noticed that you changed the original answer with "git checkout" and use "git restore" instead. It might be a good idea to keep the both, because "git restore" is a relatively new command and not available in, for example git version 2.20.1.

Comment: @VespeneGas Good point. I edited to clarify.